# How to make the clock appear on the screen after the regressive disappears

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make this clock that appears along with the beginning of the countdown only start after the element "GO!" to vanish. I already tried doing it starting after a setInterval of 6 seconds but I did not obtain result.
Please, if there is any way to debug this error even with css I thank you.

```js
  var tempo = new Number();
  tempo = 180;
      function start(){
          var number = document.getElementById("number");        
          number.innerHTML = `<div id="cinco">5</div>
                              <div id="quatro">4</div>
                              <div id="tres">3</div>
                              <div id="dois">2</div>
                              <div id="um">1</div>
                              <div id="go">GO!</div>
                             `
          ContagemRegressiva();    
      }  

      function ContagemRegressiva(){
          if(tempo >= 0){
              var minutos = parseInt(tempo / 60);
              minutos = (minutos % 60);
              var segundos = (tempo % 60);
              if(minutos < 10){
                  minutos = '0' + minutos;
                  minutos = minutos.substr(0,2); //-->
              }

              if(segundos < 10){
                  segundos = '0' + segundos;
              }

              setTimeout('ContagemRegressiva()',1000);
              tempo--;
              regressivo.innerHTML = minutos + '<font color=black>:</font>' + segundos;
              if((minutos == 00) && (segundos == 00)){
                  regressivo.innerHTML = minutos + '<font color=black>:</font>' + segundos + '<black></font>';
              }
          }
      }
```

```css
.container {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#cinco,
#quatro,
#tres,
#dois,
#um,
#go {
    font-size: 0;
    animation: .5s ease-in-out 2 forwards alternate zoom;
}

#quatro {
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

#tres {
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

#dois {
    animation-delay: 3s;
}

#um {
    animation-delay: 4s;
}

#go {
    animation-delay: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes zoom {
    0% {
        font-size: 0;
    }

    100% {
        font-size: 150px;
    }
}

@keyframes some {
    to {
        transform: scale(0);
        transform-origin: center top;
    }
}

#number {
    animation: 0.5s some linear forwards;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}

.clock{
    position: absolute;
    top: 12%;
    left: 92%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 25px;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<body onload="start()">
    <div id="number" class="container" />
    <div class="clock">
        <b style="font-size: 10"></b><span id="regressivo"></span></b><br>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why not just animate the clock appearing in CSS, like you make all the other elements disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setTimeout function to call your ContagemRegressiva function.

```
function start() {
    var number = document.getElementById("number");        
    number.innerHTML = `
    <div id="cinco">5</div>
    <div id="quatro">4</div>
    <div id="tres">3</div>
    <div id="dois">2</div>
    <div id="um">1</div>
    <div id="go">GO!</div>
    `;

    setTimeout(ContagemRegressiva, 6000);
}
```

You just need to find the amount of seconds to wait before running the function. I used 6000ms here.

Second way: you can add 'animationend' event to your #go element. When the animation on it ends, 'animationend' event will be fired.
So, you can do this with this code:

```
function start() {
    var number = document.getElementById("number");        
    number.innerHTML = `
    <div id="cinco">5</div>
    <div id="quatro">4</div>
    <div id="tres">3</div>
    <div id="dois">2</div>
    <div id="um">1</div>
    <div id="go">GO!</div>
    `;

    var goElem = document.getElementById('go');
    goElem.addEventListener('animationend', ContagemRegressiva);
}
```

Comment: If they change the timings in the CSS then this will be wrong.  It would be better to either detect the element no longer being visible, and then show the clock, or better still, do it all in CSS.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The timings in CSS may be changed, that's why I proposed to use 'animationend' event on the last appearing element before the timer should appear. Thank you for pointing on this.